# How to draw a new polyline based on exisiting polyline co-ordinates in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have parsed the co-ordinates of a polyline that I drew and exported using Google Maps. I also drew some markers on that same polyline (may not be exactly on the same polyline) whose co-ordinates also I have parsed and stored.

How can I draw a new polyline that starts from a co-ordinate of the marker in the old polyline to another on the basis of the old polyline?

I tried matching the co-ordinate of the marker with co-ordinates of the polyline to get the start and end point of the new polyline, but the co-ordinate of the marker isn't present in the polyline in most of the cases.

Comment: Try to be clearer. How did you "export" or "stored" your polyline / markers?

Comment: Also "the co-ordinate of the marker isn't present in the polyline in most of the cases" - please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineArrays

Store your markers - or polyline points - in an array and then create your polyline from that array. Hope this helps.